# Are there better tools for EEG data visualization than MNE-python?

Tags: eeg, software, visualization

I've started learning about EEG data analysis (as a data scientist working with python and R on a daily basis) and came across [MNE package](https://neuraldatascience.io/7-eeg/mne_python.html). I know that it has some tools for visualizing EEG data and I am curious if there are any better (i.e. for example faster or more visually pleasing) libraries that could be used instead. I have python based [datashader](https://datashader.org/) library on my "try it" list as it is designed to be good at visualizing big datasets faster than for example matplotlib and also looks better.